Is there a "See Also" or "Related" template?
I found two questions (here and here) that are not QUITE duplicates of each other (different fundamental question, same answer... 3^2 = 9, 3*3=9). Is there an official flag or 'See Also' template for this?

Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/201940

For similar or related questions the following format should be used to edit in links at the bottom of the question:

###See also
> [title of question](url to question)

See also

How should duplicate questions be handled?

